# Adding jquery onchange effect on select values returned by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, combobox

Alright, I have a combobox which returns values from a database. All this happens through ajax. The user can click on a button called add a new row, a new row will be generated which also will be powered by a combobox. 
However, I need to attach a 'onchange' event to the combobox returned by ajax.

I tried :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.combobox').change(function() {
  var va = $('.combobox').val();
  alert(va);
});
</script>
```

But this didn't work. I couldn't get any alert for the onchange event.

What must I try ?
Here's my ajax :-

```
try
{
  $s = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM testing2");
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();
}

$selectBegin = "";
$selectBegin = 
  '
  <select class="combobox">
    <option value=""></option>
    ';
    $innerSelectString = "";
$selectMain = "";
while($customers = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
  //fix the select thing here
  $si = "<option value='$customers->indexid'>$customers->v1</option>";
  $selectMain .= $si;
}
$selectEnd = '</select>';
$selectFinal = $selectBegin . $selectMain . $selectEnd;
return $selectFinal;
```

There are multiple comboboxes, and I have this jquery code to run combobox :-

```
function load_content_rows()
{
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
      type: "GET",
      url: "ajax.php?requestid=1",             
      dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
      success: function(response){                    
        $("#requestMaker").html(response); 
        $("#requestMaker").find(".combobox").combobox();
        //alert(response);
      }
    }); //ajax request end
  });
} //load_content
load_content_rows();
```

How do I add the onchange event to all of my comboboxes?
Here's how they look :- 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this part from the AJAX options, which might save a lot of issues:

```
dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned
```

So your AJAX request would be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function load_content_rows() {
    $.ajax({                        //create an ajax request to load_page.php
      type: "GET",
      url: "ajax.php?requestid=1",             
      success: function(response){                    
        $("#requestMaker").html(response); 
        $("#requestMaker").find(".combobox").combobox();
                                    // alert(response);
      }
    });                             // ajax request end
  }                                 //load_content
  load_content_rows();
});
```

Comment: @Akshay Can you make a full fiddle? And also, can you please check what's happening in the console?

Comment: Ok, working on the fiddle. However, php code is also included.

Comment: Try to make a [plunk](http://plnkr.co) and include the PHP response as HTML file and request for hte HTML instead.

Comment: Ok, give me 5 minutes.

Comment: @Akshay Without DB and proper set up, it is not possible to debug right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90635/discussion-between-akshay-and-praveen-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

I can't really think of anything that would stop `.change()` from working on a `<select>` element, but I don't see you bind the event after replacing and re-creating the combobox after your ajax call. It's a new element, so it will need to be bound again. Add your `.change` in the success function after calling `.combobox()` and see if that works.